# angular: display string or array

Tags: angularjs, templates

I've got an angular application and I need to handle collections of objects, that may have following attribute:

```
'field': "string string"
```

or

```
'field': ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
```

I need to display it: either a string or comma-separated list of strings.

What is the best angular way to handle such different objects? I know I might do if:block, if-not:block. But it would get extremely verbose. Is there a better way?

Comment: A custom filter can help you.

Comment: create a filter and return string or joined array from filter or use `$sce` for html. Could also be done in directive depending on use case

Comment: I'd suggest placing the logic in a filter. Do you want markup between the tokens (e.g. `<span>string1</span>, <span>string2</span>`) or plain text?

Comment: Have you tried angular built in json filter ? `| json`

Answer (score 0):

Filter is your best bet. Something like this

```
app.filter('separate', function () {
  return function (input) {
    return angular.isArray(input) ? input.join() : input;
  };
});
```

The usage is `{{ field | separate }}`.
You could do the similar thing with function defined in controller's scope, but that's what filters are for.

Also, you can output arrays in expressions without any filters, e.g. if you need it for debugging, Angular parses them to strings.